# How to pass textbox param in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I tried to pass textbox as a parameter in each render.
and tried following,

in **controller**,

```
res.render('index', { dynamic_textbox: '<input type="text" value="test" />' });
```

and in **index.ejs**,

```
<%= dynamic_textbox %>
```

It displaying result as a string not textbox..

Please any one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EJS autoescapes output by default. The following will be escaped:

```
<%= dynamic_textbox %>
```

You need to use this syntax instead, if you want to output raw HTML:

```
<%- dynamic_textbox %>
```